# Can you do a code injection in asp.net with Eval()?

Tags: injection, asp.net

I am trying to understand code injection via eval in the context of different technologies.

In the case of asp.net, is it possible to be vulnerable to code injection if i am using eval?
E.g.-
`<asp:Label ID="lbldtgCIDStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#:  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CIDStatus") %>' Visible="True" />`